# Function call inside OpenMP for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

I have the following for loop, which contains a private function call inside of it:

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    dates[i] = to_time_t(&string_dates[i][0]);
```

`to_time_t` simply converts a string (`e.g.: "18/03/2007"`) into a timestamp, and it does so with the help of `mktime()`, which is really slow. In fact, that for loop alone takes the most time out of any other code in the program. To remedy this, I am trying to apply OpenMP to the loop, like this:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    dates[i] = to_time_t(&string_dates[i][0]);
```

My OpenMP knowledge is limited, but I'm assuming that each element of the `dates` array is never accessed by two threads simultaneously since `i` is private. The same should apply to `string_dates`. But when I run this code, performance is actually worse, so I must be doing something wrong, I just don't see it. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I should have included the `to_time_t` code from the start.

```cpp
time_t to_time_t(const string * date) {
    struct std::tm tm = {0};

    istringstream ss_tm(*date);
    ss_tm >> get_time(&tm, "%m/%d/%Y");

    return mktime(&tm);
}
```

Comment: How big is `N` ?  And how do you time the execution ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark N is almost 250k, sometimes 1 milion. It depends on the dataset I'm trying this code against. To measure execution time I use ```MPI_Wtime()``` (since I'm adopting MPI as well) before and after the loop.

Comment: The issue is likely in `to_time_t()`. It may be touching some global variables or calling into library functions that keep some hidden state and are not really thread-safe. I doubt anyone could guess the actual reason without some insight into `to_time_t()`.

Comment: @HristoIliev You are absolutely right. I made an edit to add the code of that function as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `mktime()` which has a process-wide side effect. From the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime):

> Calling **mktime**() also sets the external variable *tzname* with information about the current timezone.

`mktime()` calls internally `tzset()`. The latter is serialised via a mutex lock, but what really slows it down in the multithreaded case is the constant cache trashing. When a call to `tzset()` by a thread running on a particular CPU core writes to `tzname`, this invalidates the caches of all the other cores, forcing threads that run on those cores to access higher cache levels or even the main memory the next time there is a call to `mktime()`.

You need to find or write an equivalent of `mktime()` that doesn't modify global state. Or just stick to sequential execution for that part of the code. It is perfectly fine to call `mktime()` simultaneously in multiple sequential processes (e.g., in a pure MPI application).